# Which one is good way to Import Excel to Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis

Hi i am using SQL Server 2008.

How can I import an Excel file into the database, which is the easiest way and simple to do?

1. OpenRowSet
2. BulkCopy
3. Linked Servers
4. SSIS

I have the above options to Import Excel to Database.

Comment: I would with SSIS - simple "click'n'next" wizard to guide you through the steps...

Comment: If you can perform a pre-processing task of saving the Excel file into a csv or tab delimited text, tab preferred, you will save yourself countless hours of pain and frustration. Excel is a fine data presentation tool but a terrible data transportation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion SSIS wizard is best way to import excel data where you get row and column wise whole view of table data which will be inserted and also specify column names and contraints and parse data using query.

### UPDATE :

[image]

Comment: right but can we do this in the way like,
say suppose we have already existed table and wanted to import excel and if the table is not exist then it will create the structure as per the Inputed file say suppose it should by any format .csv,.excel etc and then import perticuler file into DB. ?

Comment: yes, it will create new table as per columns in excel if table not exists. You can also specify columns in wizard.

Comment: do you have any link or code if we dont have table it will create as per the columns in Excel if table not exists. using SSIS ...

Comment: See my updated answer. you can see there is option to create table while importing data.

Answer (score 2):

If the data in your excel file does not require any processing to match your database table then I recommend you save your excel file as a csv and use a combination of BULK INSERT and the BCP.exe program.

To use BULK INSERT you will need a format file which defines how your datafile matches up to your database table.  You can write this by hand to match the existing database table or you can use the following command to generate the format file you need:

```
bcp [ServerName].[SchemaName].[TableName] format nul -c -f [FormatFileOutputName].fmt -S[ServerHostName] -U[DbUserName] -P[DbUserPassword]
```

Now you will have 2 files:

- DatafileName.csv
- FormatFileName.fmt.

Use BULK INSERT within Sql Server to insert your data.

Note: If the columns in your datafile are in a different order than your database table then you can simply edit the generated format file to have them map correctly.

Comment: To add to this answer: If your data is input comma delimited then use the -t, parameter (Note the comma aswell as the -t) to create a format file that expects comma delimited data. This will save you manually changing from the default \t